# Clarification on Sedgewick "Algorithms" heapsort chapter remark (4 ed, chapter 2.4)

Tags: algorithm, heap, priority-queue

Currently reading [Algorithms book](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Algorithms-Robert-Sedgewick/dp/032157351X). Q&A section for [chapter 2.4](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/24pq/) on [heapsort](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/24pq/Heap.java.html) implementation based on priority queue (p.328) has the following passage (let's focus on priority queue heap, not on heapsort):

> Q. I’m still not clear on the purpose of priority queues. Why exactly
>   don’t we just sort and then consider the items in increasing order in
>   the sorted array?
>
> A. In some data-processing examples such as TopM and Multiway, the
>   total amount of data is far too large to consider sorting (or even
>   storing in memory). If you are looking for the top ten entries among a
>   billion items, **do you really want to sort a billion-entry array? With
>   a priority queue, you can do it with a ten-entry priority queue.** In
>   other examples, all the data does not even exist together at any point
>   in time: we take something from the priority queue, process it, and as
>   a result of processing it perhaps add some more things to the priority
>   queue.

[TopM](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/24pq/TopM.java.html), [Multiway](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/24pq/Multiway.java.html) are simple clients of priority queue. Book speaks about 2 phases of heapsort:

1. heap construction (author uses priority queue heap, we're interested in)
2. sortdown

In my understanding heap construction is **almost** sorting ("heap order"). In order to build a heap you practically need to visit **each** item in original dataset.

**Question:** can anyone illustrate the point of author I put in **bold** in above quote? How can we build a heap without visiting all items? What I miss here? Cheers for clarif.

Comment: The short version is that heaps are suitable for external operations - i.e. using a disk or tape; in addition heaps are not the same thing as heapsort. Heapsort conceptually makes a heap, then pops off every item. For e.g. top N, you only need to pop off the top N items.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course, you have to visit all entries. Just visiting them takes O(n) time. But sorting them usually requires O(n log n) time. And as the author states, you don't have to sort all of them. Only the ten greatest elements. The basic program would look as follows:

```
allocate priority queue q with space for t entries
visit each entry e in the input array
    queueIsFull := size(q) == t
    if !queueIsFull || e > min(q)
        if !queueIsFull                
            insert e into q
        else
            exchange min(q) with e and bubble up
 next
```

The basic point here is that you remove elements from the queue as soon as you know that they are not amongst the top-t entries. Hence, the insertion and exchange do not take O(log n) time but only O(log t). This reduces the overall time from O(n log n) to O(n log t), where log t is usually much smaller than log n.

Comment: Nico, thx for code + your simple O() reasoning gave me the missing part: author basically speaks about infinite **"pipe processing" like: values stream -> bounded priority queue** which is O(n) and is a win over complexities like O(NlogN). So we basically **use priority queue as a "transformation"** to get top t elements...